# Word for undervaluing or ‘one upping’ someone else’s achievements

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m in a community where theres a lot of people who share a milestone/achievement or difficult experience, that is almost always followed by someone who goes “yea well I achieved X”, so as to undermine(?) the other.

The urban dictionary definition of “one upper” is pretty much it but I'm looking for a more appropriate word

Comment: Do you mean [like this guy](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS852US853&sxsrf=ALeKk02rxCUnVb0j0BLCawp1cKE3NRBsZg:1611542292094&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=dilbert+topper&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrgvHuhrbuAhUBHc0KHUzlBhQQ7Al6BAgHECU&biw=1719&bih=939)?

Comment: Sure, that could be an example

Comment: tchrist's link provides you with an answer: _**topper**_.

Answer (score 1):

One-upping is the common phrase for *putting down* another's achievement.

The practice of One-upmanship is longstanding and much more subtle than just saying out loud what you did to top the other's victories.
[https://www.amazon.com/One-Upmanship-Stephen-Potter/dp/1258783339](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1258783339)

Answer (score 0):

Such a person is a

> **One-upman** = A person who practises one-upmanship.
>
> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/one-upman)

> Oneupmanship = a situation in which someone does or says something in order to prove that they are better than someone else
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-upmanship)

I suspect that the term is more British, the alternative **topper** pertaining more to American usage. But I cannot substantiate this with Google ngram so hope others will comment.